# HaProxy edge redirecting to proxy port (instead of proxying) for certain URI patterns

Tags: nginx, web-server, proxy, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I'm trying to use HaProxy as my edge webserver with Nginx as my primary application server running at localhost:9180, the normal proxy behavior works fine at domain.com (it simply shows the output from :9180 at domain.com as expected), and so does domain.com/subdir/index.php - but domain.com/subdir for some reason redirects to domain.com:9180/subdir - is this some default behavior for haproxy? I can't find anything that really describes this behavior anywhere, and it could be an aspect of my Nginx config...

It may be relevant that HaProxy passes all traffic from domain.com:443 blindly to Nginx (so later it will pass domain1.com domain2.com domain3.com - etc), and then domain differentiation and application logic is handled by Nginx on a per-domain basis (configs below). I also realize some default configuration details are omitted, I'm still in an early phase so this is a raw proof of concept somewhat.

#### HaProxy config:

```
global
   tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

frontend localhost
   bind *:80
   bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/haproxy_certs/pem/ no-sslv3 no-tlsv10 no-tlsv11 ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA
   mode http
   http-request redirect scheme https unless { ssl_fc }
   default_backend localhost

backend localhost
   balance roundrobin
   mode http
   server localhost 127.0.0.1:8180 check
```

#### Nginx config:

```
server {
        listen        8180;
        server_name  domain.com;
        root         /var/www/web/domain_com;
        index index.php index.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                try_files $uri =404;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
                location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                location = /50x.html {
        }
}
```

## EDIT:

#### PHP-FPM config:

(It was suggested it could be relevant)

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; FPM Configuration ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; All relative paths in this configuration file are relative to PHP's install
; prefix.

; Include one or more files. If glob(3) exists, it is used to include a bunch of
; files from a glob(3) pattern. This directive can be used everywhere in the
; file.
include=/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Global Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[global]
; Pid file
; Default Value: none
pid = /run/php-fpm/php-fpm.pid

; Error log file
; If it's set to "syslog", log is sent to syslogd instead of being written
; in a local file.
; Default Value: /var/log/php-fpm.log
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/error.log

; syslog_facility is used to specify what type of program is logging the
; message. This lets syslogd specify that messages from different facilities
; will be handled differently.
; See syslog(3) for possible values (ex daemon equiv LOG_DAEMON)
; Default Value: daemon
;syslog.facility = daemon

; syslog_ident is prepended to every message. If you have multiple FPM
; instances running on the same server, you can change the default value
; which must suit common needs.
; Default Value: php-fpm
;syslog.ident = php-fpm

; Log level
; Possible Values: alert, error, warning, notice, debug
; Default Value: notice
;log_level = notice

; Log limit on number of characters in the single line (log entry). If the
; line is over the limit, it is wrapped on multiple lines. The limit is for
; all logged characters including message prefix and suffix if present. However
; the new line character does not count into it as it is present only when
; logging to a file descriptor. It means the new line character is not present
; when logging to syslog.
; Default Value: 1024
;log_limit = 4096

; Log buffering specifies if the log line is buffered which means that the
; line is written in a single write operation. If the value is false, then the
; data is written directly into the file descriptor. It is an experimental
; option that can potentionaly improve logging performance and memory usage
; for some heavy logging scenarios. This option is ignored if logging to syslog
; as it has to be always buffered.
; Default value: yes
;log_buffering = no

; If this number of child processes exit with SIGSEGV or SIGBUS within the time
; interval set by emergency_restart_interval then FPM will restart. A value
; of '0' means 'Off'.
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_threshold = 0

; Interval of time used by emergency_restart_interval to determine when
; a graceful restart will be initiated.  This can be useful to work around
; accidental corruptions in an accelerator's shared memory.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;emergency_restart_interval = 0

; Time limit for child processes to wait for a reaction on signals from master.
; Available units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours), or d(ays)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default Value: 0
;process_control_timeout = 0

; The maximum number of processes FPM will fork. This has been designed to control
; the global number of processes when using dynamic PM within a lot of pools.
; Use it with caution.
; Note: A value of 0 indicates no limit
; Default Value: 0
;process.max = 128

; Specify the nice(2) priority to apply to the master process (only if set)
; The value can vary from -19 (highest priority) to 20 (lowest priority)
; Note: - It will only work if the FPM master process is launched as root
;       - The pool process will inherit the master process priority
;         unless specified otherwise
; Default Value: no set
;process.priority = -19

; Send FPM to background. Set to 'no' to keep FPM in foreground for debugging.
; Default Value: yes
daemonize = yes

; Set open file descriptor rlimit for the master process.
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_files = 1024

; Set max core size rlimit for the master process.
; Possible Values: 'unlimited' or an integer greater or equal to 0
; Default Value: system defined value
;rlimit_core = 0

; Specify the event mechanism FPM will use. The following is available:
; - select     (any POSIX os)
; - poll       (any POSIX os)
; - epoll      (linux >= 2.5.44)
; Default Value: not set (auto detection)
;events.mechanism = epoll

; When FPM is built with systemd integration, specify the interval,
; in seconds, between health report notification to systemd.
; Set to 0 to disable.
; Available Units: s(econds), m(inutes), h(ours)
; Default Unit: seconds
; Default value: 10
;systemd_interval = 10

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Pool Definitions ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Multiple pools of child processes may be started with different listening
; ports and different management options.  The name of the pool will be
; used in logs and stats. There is no limitation on the number of pools which
; FPM can handle. Your system will tell you anyway :)

; See /etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf
```

Comment: Perhaps the server listening at 127.0.0.1:9000 is responsible for that redirect?

Comment: Interesting - that never possibility occurred to me, I'm using PHP-FPM with default config from the public repos for CentOS7, I'll add the config above so you can take a look

Comment: No, I don't think the php-fpm config would be responsible, but the application (and its configuration) run by php-fpm.

Comment: I see what you mean, in this instance the application is just a PHP file with an h1 tag in it, so there’s no application logic yet

Comment: OK, I'll have a closer look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this directive to your nginx server configuration:

```
port_in_redirect off;
```

Comment: Dude - my hero, I was almost certain Nginx wasn’t the problem...

Comment: You are right, it wasn't Nginx. ;-)